# What does == do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, equals

In Java, `==` is the strongest kind of equality (pointer equality): `a == b` always implies `a.equals(b)`. However, in Ruby, `==` is weaker than `.equals?`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-rc2 > 17 == 17.0
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-rc2 > 17.equal?(17.0)
 => false
```

So, where can I learn more about `==`? What kind of checks should I expect when I compare two objects with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

briefly this is what you need to know:

The `==` comparison checks whether two values are equal

`eql?` checks if two values are equal and of the same type

`equal?` checks if two things are one and the same object.

A good blog about this is [here](http://probablyinteractive.com/2008/10/27/Ruby%20Equality.html).

Comment: seems like they could have chosen better method names for eql? and equal?

Comment: CLISP is worse: `eq`, `eql`, `equal`, `equalp`, and `=`. There are better named operators like `string-equal` and `tree-equal` though.

Comment: OK, so I should never use `==` to compare two objects? But even `5` is an object in Ruby... so what is it safe to use `==` to compare? Strings and numbers, certainly. What about arrays? Hashes?

Answer (score 1):

in reality they're both just methods
== means
object.==(other_object)
equals? means
object.equals?(other_object)

In this case, though, equals is used basically for hash lookup comparison
i.e.
a_hash[1] should not be the same key value pair as a_hash[1.0]

HTH.
-r

Answer (score 1):

`==` is, simply, a method. I think it is explained really well [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/%3D%3D):

> > Typically, this method is overridden in descendent classes to provide class-specific meaning.

along with an example with `Numeric`s.

There's a pitfall here, though: as `==` is a method of the left operand, it is not always safe to assume that the result of `a==b` should be the same as of `b==a`. Especially in cases when `a` is a method call, which, in a dynamic language such as Ruby, must not always return values of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

```
jruby-1.5.0 > 17 ==17
 => true 
jruby-1.5.0 > 17 == 17.0
 => true 
jruby-1.5.0 > 17 === 17.0
 => true 
jruby-1.5.0 > 17.equal?(17.0)
 => false 
jruby-1.5.0 > 17.id
 => 35 
jruby-1.5.0 > (17.0).id
(irb):12 warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
 => 2114
```

Everything in ruby is an object. the object 17 is not the same object as 17.0 and equal? compares objects, not values of objects.